# Amount of molecule at equilibrium

Tags: biochemistry

A cell produces molecule A at 10 units per second and the molecule has a half life of 15 seconds. How many units of molecule A are inside the cell at equilibrium? Showing your work would be phenomenal.

Geez, a bit hostile, are we? Regardless,

**Here's how I went about doing it. Pardon my terrible formatting skills:**

P is the concentration of molecule A.

The half-life formula is 2^-(t/15).

At the moment of equilibrium: P = 10 * dt + 2^-(dt/15) * P

Moving things around, I get P = 10 * dt / 1-2^-(dt/15)

I attempt to take lim dt->0 using l'hopital's: 10 / (1/15 * ln(2)) = 150/ln(2) molecules of A at equilibrium.

However, the correct answer should be 300 units of molecule A at equilibrium. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, showing your work would be phenomenal.

Comment: this looks a lot like homework.  Homework questions aren't forbidden, but this isn't a "do-your-homework-for-you" service; you have to show what you've tried and where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: Phenomenal. Finished editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a very similar question from you [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/67213/finding-steady-state-concentration-given-half-life-and-production-rate/67260#67260). Using the formulas on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life#Formulas_for_half-life_in_exponential_decay) we can find that the mean lifetime $\tau$ is $T_{1/2}/\ln(2) = 15/\ln(2) \approx 21.6$.  Using [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) the steady state concentration is (arrival rate) $\times$ (mean lifetime) $\approx 216$.

You could also use the decay rate $\lambda=\ln(2)/T_{1/2}$ and substitute it into the differential equation given in the previous answer.

This is the same as the answer that you got to by a more complicated route. I don't see how we can get to a steady-state concentration of 300 unless you've misstated the question or left something out.

Comment: A friend just told me the same thing. Perhaps the answer key is faulty.